# iOS アプリを Windows 環境で開発するために必要なツールを知りたい

Tags: ios, windows

iPhoneのiOSアプリを開発をしたいのですが私のパソコンはWindowsです。
ググりましたが古い情報ばかりでよくわかっていません。
どのようなツールを使えば良いのでしょうか？

Comment: 例えば`ios application development by windows pc`で検索した結果とかを見てみてください。[HOW TO DEVELOP IOS APPS ON WINDOWS](https://mindster.com/how-develop-ios-apps-windows/), [Xcode for Windows: Develop iOS Apps on PC](https://learnappmaking.com/xcode-for-windows-how-to/), [Xcode for Windows (12 Ways to Build iOS Apps on PC)](https://codewithchris.com/xcode-for-windows/), [How to Develop iOS Apps on Windows](https://blog.devmountain.com/how-to-develop-ios-apps-on-windows/), [How to develop iOS apps on Windows](https://www.eltima.com/ios-development-on-windows/)

Comment: 日本語で新しめの記事はこの辺。[Appleのプログラミング言語「Swift」がWindows 10へ移植...](https://forest.watch.impress.co.jp/docs/news/1278413.html), [GoogleのエンジニアがSwiftをWindowsに移植](https://www.infoq.com/jp/news/2020/10/swift-for-windows-released/), [SwiftをWindws10にインストールしてみました](http://linksquare.biz/programming/swift%E3%82%92windws10%E3%81%AB%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BF%E3%81%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F.html), [...WindowsでiOSアプリ開発を始めたかった](https://qiita.com/sivertigo/items/90b004a88240f24ea2dc), [\[iPhone\] Xcode をインストールする, iOSアプリ作成準備](https://i-app-tec.com/ios/xcode-install.html)